# .htaccess rules for blocking bots with an extra condition

Tags: multisite, htaccess, rewrite-rules, security, mod-rewrite

I have a WP multisite installed. I am integrated with Ezoic and Cloudflare. I had implemented firewall rules. However, I have an issue blocking bots that have `X-Middleton` in the `User-Agent`, because my origin server allows it, for detecting real user IPs.

The `X-Middleton` is appended when the bots pass through Ezoic that acts as a reverse proxy.  I had inserted a rule in the `.htaccess` but it is not working, because the origin server allows every request that has `X-Middleton`.

The rule is as follows:

```
# BLOCK BOTS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(ADmantX|Proximic|Barkrowler).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

It is possible a rule that blocks by user agent if the "bad-bot" has `X-Middleton` in the `User-Agent`?

Comment: Not sure that I follow? Have you tried modifying that rule for "X-Middleton"?

Comment: Thanks Mr White I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (ADmantX|Proximic|Barkrowler|X-Middleton) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will block any request where the `User-Agent` string *contains* either `ADmantX`, `Proximic`, `Barkrowler` or `X-Middleton`. The `NC` flag makes this a case-insensitive match - whether this is strictly required or not in this example I don't know, but generally this should be a case-sensitive match, since `User-Agents` (even from bad bots) is usually consistent with regards to *case*.

The regex prefix `^.*` and suffix `.*$` are superfluous.

The regex pattern `(A|B|C|D)` is called *alternation*. Essentially means `A` or `B` or `C` or `D` will match.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `.*` can be simplified to `^` - which is also marginally more efficient, since you don't need to actually match anything here, just to be successful.

The `L` flag is not required when the `F` flag is used - it is implied.

---

**UPDATE:**

It appears that `X-Middleton` (or rather `X-Middleton/1`) is appended to *all* User-Agent strings that reach your site, as they pass through the Ezoic *reverse proxy*. So, simply blocking based on the presence of this string in the User-Agent header (as above) is not going to work, since it will block all requests!

If `X-Middleton` is simply appended to the UA string and no further processing occurs then you could theoretically block the request when `X-Middleton` appears twice (or more times) in the UA string in order to block any request where `X-Middleton` occurs in the original request.

To handle this situation you would create an additional rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (X-Middleton).*\1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`\1` is an internal backreference that matches the first matched subpattern, ie. "X-Middleton". So, it is only successful when the string "X-Middleton" occurs at least twice, separated by any number of characters (or none).

The above will block `blah X-Middleton blah X-Middleton/1`, but not `blah blah X-Middleton/1` (case-insensitive match).

However, I would want to see an example access log entry (User-Agent string) of such a request before going live with this. It shouldn't block real user requests, but it might not block fake requests either. If you don't have an actual fake request, then you can mock one up by customising the User-Agent string your browser sends (in Chrome's "Inspector" > Customize Menu > More tools > Network conditions OR install a User-Agent switcher plugin) OR use CURL to make the request, eg. `curl -A "<custom-user-agent>" <siteurl>` - where you'd set `<custom-user-agent>` to `blah X-Middleton blah` or something.

I would also be interested to see the complete list of HTTP request headers that are reaching your application server, as there may be a better way to solve this. (I find it unusual that an intermediate proxy would modify the User-Agent, without also providing the original value. Although, [maybe there are no additional options](https://support.ezoic.com/kb/article/how-to-fix-origin-errors)?)

Comment: Very didactic, thanks. However I have a question. All the requests that pass through Ezoic have the `X-Middleton` in the `user-agent`. This rule is not going to block all the real users?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain correctly. All the requests that pass through Ezoic append the `X-Middleton` in the `user-agent` good bots, bad bots and real users.

Comment: Mmmm, yeah, I wondered about that after posting my answer. If _all_ requests contain `X-Middleton` in the User-Agent then you obviously can't block simply based on the presence of that substring (which is what we're doing above). How, specifically, does Ezoic modify the User-Agent? Does it always _append_ `X-Middleton` to the end of the `User-Agent`? So, if it was present in the initial request, it would now appear twice?

Comment: Or does Ezoic provide the original User-Agent string in a different HTTP response header? (A "reverse proxy" should not _destroy_ elements of the original client request - so I suspect this information is still available _somewhere_.)

Comment: The requests shows as follows

`186.81.XXX.XXX - - [03/Mar/2021:19:55:27 +0000] "GET /es/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx HT TP/1.1" 200 11512 "https://example.com/es/xxxxx/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Safari/537 .36 X-Middleton/1"`

`13.66.XXX.XXX - - [03/Mar/2021:19:53:00 +0000] "GET /es/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 36675 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2. 0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) X-Middleton/1"`

Comment: What about an access log entry for a request you would want to block? Also, what are the HTTP request headers that are reaching your application server?

Comment: I use Cloudflare firewall rules

Comment: Yes, but you are implementing this blocking directive in your Apache `.htaccess` file on your application (origin) server, so my queries above still apply. We need to know more information about the request that you want to block, before we can construct a rule to block it. After all, how will you test it to make sure it's working?

Comment: They change to lower case:
`148.72.152.68 - - [03/Mar/2021:21:07:54 +0000] "GET /es/xxx-xxx-xxxx HTTP/1.0" 403 560 "-" "ias-or/3.1 ( +https://www.admantx.com/service-fetcher.html) X-Middleton/1 "`

`54.91.119.82 - - [28/Feb/2021:02:31:04 +0000] GET /es/xxx-xx/ HTTP/1.0 200 22755 - Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +https://www.comscore.com/Web-Crawler) X-Middleton/1`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? What changes to lowercase?

Comment: If I remember correctly before the name of the bot appeared somewheres in the' user- agent' in upper and lower case, as it was in the rule

Comment: I don't think that is particularly conclusive. When `admantx` is part of the domain name (as in your example) then it should be all lowercase. And `proximic` should also be all lowercase anyway in the example UAs I've seen... https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/proximic-search/

Comment: You can output a list of the HTTP request headers that your site sees... create a PHP page and dump the `$_SERVER` superglobal array and all the elements that start `HTTP_` are the HTTP headers. Also, an example of the access log for a request that contains `X-Middleton` in the _original_ User-Agent string... you can mock this up yourself by changing your UA string (browser extension or using CURL etc.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try with your updated answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which part of the rule did you changed.